# Waiting to send email

Tags: workflow, email

I have a workflow that will not send email out when when a date has been reached. If I make a change or create a new item with the contidition is true it works but if the condition is false and I want it to wait it doesn't work. please help.

[image]

Comment: I also need to know how to deal with blank "Term date".

Comment: I updated the pic to show my new workflow.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to change the current item:term end date to "Short Date".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run two actions in parallel: one that watches the date and the other that monitors changes. It is well explained here:

http://amarkeev.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/item-expiration-reminders-in-sharepoint-using-workflow/

Comment: So with this solution do I need to create a seperate workflow for each reminder (90, 60, 30) or will it know to wait on each step?

Answer (score 0):

another apporach is usie the calculate columns and add the formula to calculate the value on the basis of created item, in Workflow use the logic .
here are detailed steps:
http://mysharepointchronicles.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/sharepoint-list-with-workflow-email-reminder-set-to-send-30-days-from-created-date/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a workflow to be activated (Approval, Collect Feedback, Collect Signatures) once the date is reached.